# Why is the else part of my if/then statement not being used?

Tags: c#

I have an Entity Framework Core project with this `HttpPut` method inside of my controllers.

I have an if/else statement that checks two booleans, `isValid` and `isDeleted`.

In testing, when I send over an object to the controller with `isValid` set to true and `isDeleted` set to false, it send the correct email.

But if I send over an object with `isValid` set to true and `isDeleted` set to true, it doesn't send out an email.

Is my code logic out of hand crazy?

thanks!

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutShoppingCart(long id, [FromBody] ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
    {

        _context.Entry(shoppingCart).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ShoppingCartExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        
        if (shoppingCart.IsValid && !shoppingCart.IsDeleted)
        {
            try
            {
                _customerEmailerProcess.SendCustomerEmail(shoppingCart,10);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(this.Response, "<script>alert('" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex) + "')</script>");
            }
        } else
        {
            if (shoppingCart.IsDeleted)
            {
                try
                {
                    _customerEmailerProcess.SendCustomerEmail(shoppingCart, 20);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(this.Response, "<script>alert('" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex) + "')</script>");
                }
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Comment: `!shoppingCart.IsDeleted` is with not operator, when you set both true it becomes false, and there is also && operator between both conditions, that makes it overall false, you can put OR `A || B` to make it true in any case

Comment: !shoppingCart.IsDeleted this become false in the case of true.

Comment: @SANDEEP I want the first email to be sent out if `IsValid` is true and if `IsDeleted` is false.  If `IsDeleted` is true, then I want it to send out the second email.  So should I switch them?  Thanks!

Comment: chnage the line with if (shoppingCart.IsValid && shoppingCart.IsDeleted==false). it will work if your input for IsDeleted is false for first mail.

Comment: Your boolean logic looks OK, albeit a bit confusing.  Are you sure that an exception is not being thrown?

Comment: if logic still not clear try to put IsDeleted in an additional set brackets `if((!shoppingCart.IsDeleted) && shoppingCart.IsValid)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your if/else statement should work, so my guess is that there is a problem in the SendCustomerEmail method when the second parameter is 20.  Does the method expect the shoppingCart object to have IsValid set to true?

The easiest thing to do to solve it is run it through the debugger and step through it with the shoppingCart.IsDeleted property set to false.